# How to use forward declared struct data in another .c file?

Tags: c

I have a struct which is forward declared in file.h. The structure is defined in file1.c. I'm trying to use the struct in file2.c. But it is giving me "error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" in file2.c.

**file.h**

```
typedef struct foo foo;
```

**file1.c**

```
#include <file.h>

typedef struct foo {
   int val;
} foo;
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <file.h>

struct foo *f;
.
.
.
printf("%d", f->val);   <--Error here
```

I don't have any issue if I define the struct in file.h. Is there any way I can use val in file2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called an opaque `struct`, is useful when you want to protect the access to the members (a kind of private specifier).

in this way, only `file1.c` can access the members of the `struct`, to make it visible to the rest of the .c files you need to

1) Define the `struct` inside the .h file

or

2) Access the members through a function:

```
//file.h

typedef struct foo foo;
int foo_val(const foo *);

//file1.c

#include "file.h" // Always prefer "" instead of <> for local headers

struct foo { // Notice that you don't need to retypedef the struct
   int val;
};

int foo_val(const foo *f)
{
    return f->val;
}

//file2.c

#include "file.h"

struct foo *f;

printf("%d", foo_val(f));
```